# Asana API: How do I set the Section of a Task on My Tasks

Tags: ruby, asana, asana-api

Asana has [Sections on the My Tasks View](https://blog.asana.com/2021/09/customize-my-tasks/).  I want to use the Asana Ruby API to update the My Tasks Section of a given pre-existing task.

I have been spending hours trying to get this to work on the latest version of the [Ruby Asana API Gem](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana).

The API support for this new feature seems spotty, but [this thread indicates it's possible](https://forum.asana.com/t/changing-task-section/57402/7) using the `/tasks/task-id/addProject` endpoint.

Attempting to hit this endpoint with the Asana Ruby Gem is not working for me:

```
@client.tasks.add_project_for_task(task_gid: task.gid, section: section_id, project: ENV['my_tasks_project_id'])
```

This gives:

> Asana::Errors::InvalidRequest: section: Not the correct type

Okay, so that's presumably because it's a special My Tasks section, rather than a typical project section.  So let's try with `assignee_section`

```
@client.tasks.add_project_for_task(task_gid: task.gid, assignee_section: section_id, project: ENV['my_tasks_project_id'], options: {pretty: true})
```

No error from this, but it does nothing.  So how do I set the My Tasks section of a pre-existing task with the Ruby Asana gem?

It might be that the Asana Ruby SDK is too out of date to do this at all, and I need to write a custom body for the request.  I'd be interested in how to write such a custom body request from within the gem, if a raw/custom body is the only way.

Comment: Where is the actual API documentation?  The gem is largely a ruby wrapper for standard api calls. Well I found [docs here](https://developers.asana.com/docs/asana). There doesn't appear to be anything Ruby specific here. Your question seems related to the API itself, not the gem code. Your "presumably" presumes a lot.  Hard to help on this because it doesn't seem like a code question.

Comment: It's a wrapper for the API, yes.  I'd like to use the gem to hit the API and do this-- that's the code I'd like.  If this specific api call isn't available through the gem, I'd like to still use the gem in some kind of manual way (so I can still take advantage of its built in auth, and keep the pattern of using it in my codebase) to make the API request.

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation?  I would suggest using [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test that the actual pure API call you're trying to make is valid and returns expected data. Once you confirm this, then we can be of help.

Comment: That's my plan if I don't get an answer.  I also have not done a custom request with the gem. I want to go minimal levels of abstraction down, with the gem handling as much as possible, and least code possible, so would have to dig into the poorly documented gem as well. Then I'll post my own answer.  I will post the answer after doing that, but want to give it a day or 2 to see if someone has done this already.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, just set `task_updates[:assignee_section]` with the My Tasks section Gid. Then `task.update(task_updates)`

My Task sections are fundamentally different than normal Project sections.  Hope this helps future people